# Unable to parse, FomatStyle

Tags: java, javafx, java-time

In my app, When I select '20:45' to TimePicker, it formatted like '8:45 pm'
I can reproduce the problem with the following code:

```
String input = "8:45pm";
LocalTimeStringConverter converter = new LocalTimeStringConverter(FormatStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(converter.fromString(input));
```

which throws an exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8:45pm' could not be parsed at index 4
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
at javafx.util.converter.LocalDateTimeStringConverter$LdtConverter.fromString(LocalDateTimeStringConverter.java:208)
at javafx.util.converter.LocalTimeStringConverter.fromString(LocalTimeStringConverter.java:119)
at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTimePickerContent.updateValue(JFXTimePickerContent.java:427)
at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTimePickerContentTest.updateValue(JFXTimePickerContentTest.java:11)
```

How can I fix this problem?

## Update1

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8:35 PM' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
    at javafx.util.converter.LocalDateTimeStringConverter$LdtConverter.fromString(LocalDateTimeStringConverter.java:208)
    at javafx.util.converter.LocalTimeStringConverter.fromString(LocalTimeStringConverter.java:119)
    at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTimePickerContent.updateValue(JFXTimePickerContent.java:424)
    at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTimePickerContentTest.updateValue(JFXTimePickerContentTest.java:11)
```

## Solution

Java get default locale for JVM from windows preference.

My default locale for JVM was korean and It thorws an exception even I set LocalTimeStringConverter to English.

We can set the locale for jvm in several ways. [oracle Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using)

Or change the code. following code is:

```
String input = "8:45pm";
input = input.toUpperCase(); // DateTimeFormatter expects "PM" (uppercase)
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalTimeStringConverter converter = new LocalTimeStringConverter(dtf, dtf);
System.out.println(converter.fromString(input));
```

Like Hugo says.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input string is `8:45pm` and `FormatStyle.SHORT` expects a space before `pm`, I used a `DateTimeFormatter` instead:

```
String input = "8:45pm";
input = input.toUpperCase(); // DateTimeFormatter expects "PM" (uppercase)
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalTimeStringConverter converter = new LocalTimeStringConverter(dtf, dtf);
System.out.println(converter.fromString(input));
```

The output is:

> 20:45

Comment: This is makes my app working charm. But, I want to know the problem with using FormatStyle.SHORT

Comment: In my tests I noticed that `FormatStyle.SHORT` expects a space between the minutes and "PM" (so it works only if the input is `8:45 PM` (with a space after "5")

Comment: I already tested you said. input is "8:45 PM" But it still throw an same exception. I updated this exception ( Update1)

Comment: I've made some tests here. Basically, with `FormatStyle.SHORT` it only works if input is `8:45 PM` (anything else throws Exception). And with `DateTimeFormatter` (the code in my answer above), it only works if input is `8:45pm` or `8:45PM` (because I'm using `toUpperCase` method, so both cases will work).

Answer (score 3):

The predefined format for english-locale time values is 'HH:MM {A/P}M'. So first, there has to be a space between your time and the 'pm' string, second 'pm' must be uppercase. See also this java tutorial page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html

```
String input = "8:45 PM";
```

Cheers!

Comment: I tried using your code, but it still throws an same exception

Comment: Can you post the exception message again after making sure that 'fromString(input)' is getting '8:45 PM' as input?

Answer (score 1):

This format accepts slightly different style, so your input must be converted to "8:45 PM".

```
String input = "8:45pm";
input = input.replaceAll("pm", " PM").replaceAll("am", " AM");
LocalTimeStringConverter converter = new LocalTimeStringConverter(FormatStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(converter.fromString(input));
```

However, java.time.format.FormatStyle docs says:

```
/**
 * Short text style, typically numeric.
 * For example, the format might be '12.13.52' or '3:30pm'.
 */
SHORT;
```

I guess, this needs to be fixed.

Comment: I tried using your code, but it still throws an same exception

Comment: Seems fine to me, are you sure your string is replaced to "8:45 PM" ?

Comment: Yes. I had tried this code by other computer. But still not work. My jdk version is "8u110"